# Baby kicks and wakes himself

Tags: infant, development, sleep-training

This is a strange one for us, especially me. My 3 1/2 month old has disturbed sleep, as he kicks and moves his hands while becoming stiff, and wakes himself up.

We tried wrapping him up but he is too good at moving his hands out and again wakes himself up. This thing make his sleep disturbed, and my wife takes it that he is hungry and pulls him into our bed while feeding him but it's not enough, so this goes on throughout.

Why does he kick, move and stiffen himself? Wrapping him isn't working as he has grown too big to get wrapped in a baby blanket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this behavior occur on a daily basis or just sometimes?

For me it reads like your boy is working through something in his sleep. Do you have any toys which really sets him up, or something flashy , fast moving, he sees all day?

Have you as a father tried to comfort him? One would think the mother is the best person to calm a baby down, but the baby can smell its mother and especially its mothers breast. Babys can get a little bit excited, when  they can smell it and in some cases that does the opposite of calming it down.

When our boy wakes up at night, I take him and hear some music we listen to since he was a newborn and in 90% of all cases the issue is closed within 5 minutes.

Comment: It is now and it is very disturbing and now he has stopped drinking milk as well, his mother tried to feed him that works well but she can't do it all the time and the moment we lay him in his crib, same action on kicking and hand movements to wake himself up.

Comment: Does he fall asleept next to his mother and stays quite? How he reacts on pacifiers?

Comment: Yes he does sleep next to mom n do same time to time, he is ok with pacifiers.

Comment: Moreover his newly habit is not drinking milk from bottle, it's been days now.

Comment: Have you tried different caps? My boy also never drunk from bottle, his mom feed him all the time. We used a crip with one side open, that we could place directly beside the bed, so she could lay beside him and feed him at demand. That was quite comfortable for both. We called it the docking station ;) To ease you, that all does not sound unusual to me. You just did not find what he wants from you. Keep calm in presence of the baby, try different things and have some patience. Do you had a midwife? Maybe she has a tip.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a combination of [Moro reflex](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/003293.htm) (also called a startle reflex, or startle response) and normal movements in sleep. Infants have less control over their muscles and reactions than older children, and so their more extreme movements are more likely to wake them up.

If the waking is just caused by startling himself, then comforting him with a cuddle should quickly get him back to sleep. If he then becomes fussier, however, there is more likely another underlying issue (diaper, hunger) that requires more intervention.